# Using WebRTC getstats() and Chrome: How can I get bytesSent and BytesReceived for Remote Peer

Tags: google-chrome, webrtc

I'm trying to use the `getStats()` API to get various statistics about the WebRTC connection on Chrome. Particularly, I want to obtain the `bytesSent` and `bytesReceived` for both the local and remote peers. While I am able to obtain statistics for the local end of the connections via (`inbound-rtp` and `outbound-rtp`) Stats, Chrome does not seem to have implemented those statistics for the `remote-inbound-rtp` and `remote-outbound-rtp` stat reports. (as per [this comparison chart](https://webrtc-stats.callstats.io/verify))

So my question is, is there some workaround to achieve this somehow and extract the information for the remote peer?